# How to use dbt_utils.unique_combination_of_columns on DBT

Tags: dbt, dbtype

How could anyone help me how to use this DBT command "dbt_utils.unique_combination_of_columns" I plan to test 2 different column on my DBT unfortunately (user_id & ticker_symbol) I'm encountering an error upon  running dbt test. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Screen of my yaml file

[image]

Screenshot of my .sql

[image]

Error encountered upon running DBT test:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This dbt_utils generic test is thought to be ran on top of a model, not on a particular column, so you'd need to place it under the model name and not to a certain column.

So, instead of what you did in the screenshot, you could do the following:

```yaml
# this is your schema.yml

version: 2

models:
  
  - name: mrt_test
    description: ""
    tests:
      - dbt_utils.unique_combination_of_columns:
          combination_of_columns:
            - user_id
            - ticker_symbol
    columns:
      - name: (...)
```

Comment: I tried to use this yml, unfortunately its not working from my end

version: 2

models:

  - name: mrt_test
    columns:
      - name: surrogate_keys
        tests:
          - dbt_utils.unique_combination_of_columns:
              combination_of_columns:  
                - user_id
                - ticker_symbol
        columns:
      - name: (user_id, ticker_symbol)

Comment: version: 2

models:

  - name: mrt_test
    columns:
      - name: surrogate_keys
        tests:
          - dbt_utils.unique_combination_of_columns:
              combination_of_columns:  
                - user_id
                - ticker_symbol
        columns:
      - name: (surrogate_keys)

Comment: You don't need to enclose the column name in brackets, that was just an example I put, meaning that you just need to input the name of whatever column you want to include in the schema.yml.

Comment: Be sure that the combination_of_columns is indented sufficiently.  It needs to be two tabs indented past the previous line.  Otherwise, dbt errored with a parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to this is to create a single-column surrogate key in your table as detailed in [this](https://docs.getdbt.com/blog/sql-surrogate-keys) and [this](https://www.getdbt.com/blog/the-most-underutilized-function-in-sql/) dbt blog posts  This creates a primary key for your table using the dbt_utils package and the unique/not_null tests innate to dbt can be used on this field.  There are tradeoffs to adding an additional field to every table, but it provides ease and uniformity of testing across all models.

Your model would look something like this:

```
WITH final AS (
....
)

SELECT 
  md5({{ dbt_utils.generate_surrogate_key([
    'column1',
    'column2']) }}) AS surrogate_key
  ,*
FROM final
```